# ImportError: cannot import name 'convert_from_path'

Tags: python, importerror

[image: This is my code and error]

I am trying to convert pdf to image. So I'm doing it using the pdf2image library. But somehow I get this error

> ImportError: cannot import name 'convert_from_path'

keeps showing up. When I try to run the same code in command prompt it seems to work. But in Sublime editor this error keeps showing up.

Comment: Please add a sniper of code you tried and a sample data as well as error message here, so we can help you better. Thank you.

Comment: **Done**. I have updated an image showing my code and the error message.

Comment: You can improve your question by copying your code so others can use it to work on the problem. And maybe a sample file. And here, you have an import error. The line `from pdf2image import convert_from_path` cannot be imported. Please check your method name and make sure pdf2image is installed. If you do not have it installed, you can `pip install pdf2image` in command prompt (or similar command depending on your environment) to install it.

Comment: As I mentioned above, it worked when I used command-line interpreter. So yes, it is definitely installed and I have cross checked by typing the command again which showed me that the requirement is already satisfied.

Comment: Maybe your interpreter is using a different environment? This usually happens when you have multiple environment (or pythons) installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your error message, you seem to have a file named *pdf2image.py* in the same directory as your main script.

```
File "/home/raheeb/Downloads/Telegram Desktop/New python/pdf_conversion.py" ...
  from pdf2image.exceptions import convert_from_path
File "/home/raheeb/Downloads/Telegram Desktop/New python/pdf2image.py" ...
  from pdf2image import convert_from_path                     ^^
                                                              ||
                                                              ||
```

You need to rename that, because your main script is importing from *that* pdf2image.py instead of the *actual* [pdf2image](https://pypi.org/project/pdf2image/) module which I assume is what you have installed and should be the one you actually need.

As to why it imports that instead of the true module, you need to read the [Module Search Path](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#the-module-search-path) from the Python docs. Basically, it first searches for modules in the same directory as your script, before it searches from the installation environment.